# Find longest substring in an array of strings and remove it from all the elements in the array

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, search

I have this array, for example (the size is variable):

```
x = ["10111", "10122", "10250", "10113"]
```

I need to find the longest string that is a substring of each array element ("10" in this case) (it need not to be a prefix of the strings). I have to remove it from all the strings. The output for this example would be:

```
x=["111","222","250","113"] //common value = "10"
```

Comment: Is the most common substring supposed to be at the beginning? Also, is this homework?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Go through posts at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org

Comment: The most common substring in your example is `1`. This appears 10 times. `10` appears only 4 times.

Comment: Is the most common substring one that must be contained in **all** arrays or the one that is most common?

Comment: @LeeTaylor forgot to mention, largest substring as well

Comment: @user1785050: So this is what my [method below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953894/284240) does, do you need further assistance? I must admit that it's not an algorithm but a C# implementation. But i'm sure that you can transfer it to C since the core of it is a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this works perfect, I suppose it is a basic algorithm where we find the sub-string combinations of a string and check with the substrings of the rest(eliminating unnecessary). Thanks. Let me know if you can improve the algorithm. As of now this works for me.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: The most common substring in those strings is the empty string. It appears before and after each character of every string, infinitely many times.

Comment: @user1785050: People are voting to close this question in part because you have not made the problem clear. Must the substring being sought be a prefix of the strings? (A prefix of a string is a substring that starts at the beginning of the containing string.) Must it be in all the strings or just be the most frequent? If it need not be a prefix, why is the answer not “1” rather than “10”, since there are more occurrences of “1” in the sample strings than there are of “10”?

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I mentioned in my earlier comment that I have to get the largest substring. It is not necessarily a prefix string.

Comment: There are four largest substrings, “10111”, “10122“, “10250”, and “10113”. So that is the wrong phrase; you do not want the largest substring. Perhaps you want the largest substring that is in all the strings. If so, them the words “most common” in the title and the second sentence of the body are wrong; you do not want the most common substring, just any string that is in all the given strings and is longer than all other such strings, regardless of how common it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This extension finds the longest most common substring(s). Note that `"1"` is also contained in every string even more often than `"10"`. (C# only):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetMostCommonSubstrings(this IList<string> strings)
    {
        if (strings == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("strings");
        if (!strings.Any() || strings.Any(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
            throw new ArgumentException("None string must be empty", "strings");

        var allSubstrings = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
        {
            var substrings = new List<string>();
            string str = strings[i];
            for (int c = 0; c < str.Length - 1; c++)
            {
                for (int cc = 1; c + cc <= str.Length; cc++)
                {
                    string substr = str.Substring(c, cc);
                    if (allSubstrings.Count < 1 || allSubstrings.Last().Contains(substr))
                        substrings.Add(substr);
                }
            }
            allSubstrings.Add(substrings);
        }
        if (allSubstrings.Last().Any())
        {
            var mostCommon = allSubstrings.Last()
                .GroupBy(str => str)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Length)
                .ThenByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Select(g => g.Key);
            return mostCommon;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Now it's easy:

```
string[] x = new[] { "10111", "10122", "10250", "10113" };
string mostCommonSubstring = x.GetMostCommonSubstrings().FirstOrDefault();
if (mostCommonSubstring != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        x[i] = x[i].Replace(mostCommonSubstring, "");
}
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", x));
```

output:

```
111, 122, 250, 113
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/dCBAir)</kbd>

---

**Edit**: If you just want to find the longest common substring without taking the frequency of occurrence into account you can use this optimzed approach(O(n) operation) using a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx):

```
public static string GetLongestCommonSubstring(this IList<string> strings)
{
    if (strings == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("strings");
    if (!strings.Any() || strings.Any(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
        throw new ArgumentException("None string must be empty", "strings");

    var commonSubstrings = new HashSet<string>(strings[0].GetSubstrings());
    foreach (string str in strings.Skip(1))
    {
        commonSubstrings.IntersectWith(str.GetSubstrings());
        if (commonSubstrings.Count == 0)
            return null;
    }
    return commonSubstrings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetSubstrings(this string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        throw new ArgumentException("str must not be null or empty", "str");

    for (int c = 0; c < str.Length - 1; c++)
    {
        for (int cc = 1; c + cc <= str.Length; cc++)
        {
            yield return str.Substring(c, cc);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in this way:

```
string[] x = new[] { "101133110", "101233210", "102533010", "101331310" };
string longestCommon = x.GetLongestCommonSubstring();  // "10"
```

Comment: this works perfect, I suppose it is a basic algorithm where we find the sub-string combinations of a string and check with the substrings of the rest(eliminating unnecessary). Thanks. Let me know if you can improve the algorithm. As of now this works for me.

Comment: @user1785050: There's always room for improvement. However, until performance is not a real issue i would keep it as it is since unnecessary micro-optimization makes code less readable and maintainable.

Comment: What is the purpose of `allSubstrings.Last().Contains(substr)` in the `if` statement? You are collecting strings for consideration only if they are substrings of the most recent previously collected string? What happens with “111”, “222”, “222”? Will the “222” strings not be collected, even though they are more common?

Comment: What does “longest most common substring” mean? If it means the longest of the substrings that are tied for most common, it would be “1” in the given strings. How can this phrase refer to the “10” the OP seeks?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: No, "222" will be omitted since it is one constraint that **all** strings must contain this substring. That's also the reason why i just have to look at the last substring collection to find all common substrings.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: "longest common substring" means: the longest(in terms of character count) common (in all) substring. If two substrings with the same character count are in all strings the one that is contained more often will be taken(`.ThenByDescending(g => g.Count())`).

Comment: The question does not state the substring it seeks must be in all strings.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's why i've asked it in the comments. But even if OP hasn't answered it he stated that it works perfectly. So apparently my assumption was correct. It's  also not unreasonable to translate _common_ with _in all_ and the sample data also  suggests it.

Comment: @user1785050: Edited my answer to provide another - more efficient -approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The assertion of the OP that this answer works is inadequate to clarify the question. In the example given, the longest common substring, the longest common prefix, and the longest of the most common prefix are identical. Therefore, a solution that finds the string that is all three of these things is insufficient to distinguish between these things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (I suppose the common string should be at the beginning):

```
string[] x = {"10111","10222","10250","10113"};
string common = x[0];
foreach(var i in x){
  while(!i.StartsWith(common)){
    common = common.Substring(0,common.Length-1);
    if(common == "") break;
  }
}
x = x.Select(a=>a.Substring(common.Length)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This works only if they begin every time with 10. With this sequence for example it does not work: {"11110","12210","11210","22110"};

Comment: @Regu **I stated clearly that `I suppose the common string should be at the beginning`**, that's because the OP didn't make it clear

Answer (score 1):

Find the maximum number of times a substring of length 1 appears.  This is a simple O(n^2) search.  Call this maximum number of occurrence K.

In your example, this is "1", "0", and K=5.

Now you know that all substrings of length 2 cannot appear in more than K input strings.  Also, any substring that occurs K times must be made of the length 1 substrings that occured K times.  Search the length 1 substrings for substrings of length 2 that exist K times, this is again a simple O(n^2) search.

Repeat for longer lengths until no more substrings exist in K inputs.