# Intersect two lists and return the similarity with the preserved order of the original first string value

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I'm facing a problem I don't even know what to search in Google/Stack Overflow.
So comment if you feel the need for further explanation, questions.

Basically I want to intersect two lists and return the similarity with the preserved order of the original first string value.

Example:

I have two strings, that I convert to a CharArray.
I want to Intersect these two arrays and return the values that are similar, **including/with the order of the first string (s1)**.

---

As you can see the first string contains **E15** (in that specific order), and so does the seconds one.

So these two strings will return : { 'E', '1', '5' }

```
string s1 = "E15QD(A)";
string s2 = "NHE15H";
```

The problem I am facing is that if i replace "s2" with:

```
string s2 = "NQE18H" // Will return {'Q', 'E', '1' }
```

My operation will return : {'Q', 'E', '1' }

The result **should** be : {'E', '1' } because **Q** don't follow the letter **1**

Currently my operation is not the greatest effort, because i don't know which methods to use in .NET to be able to do this.

Current code:

```
List<char> cA1 = s1.ToList();
List<char> cA2 = s2.ToList();

var result = cA1.Where(x => cA2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Feel free to help me out, pointers in the right direction is acceptable as well as a full solution.

Comment: Using `Intersect` will give you the Order from first string[Example Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KqSIPC). But your requirement  suggest that You might want to write the your own [Intersect with custom equality comparer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340273/intersect-with-a-custom-iequalitycomparer-using-linq)

Comment: What should be the output for `s1="AXBYC"` and `s2="ABACUS"`?

Comment: @CoderofCode Will look in to that right away.

Comment: I guess you're looking for a way to find the [longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring). Here's also a C# implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953894/284240

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that should return { 'A' } . As the first character in both words is alike (has no previous letter)

Comment: @J.Olsson Why not `"ABC"`? Should the characters be next to each other to be considered "in order"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, i think i've been digging to deep to see it that way. Will look int to this also. (Thats awesome)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes. I'm sorry that i did not specify that. The letters should be next to eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ["longest common substring"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring) problem.

You can use this extension to get all substrings lazily:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSubstrings(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            throw new ArgumentException("str must not be null or empty", "str");

        for (int c = 0; c < str.Length - 1; c++)
        {
            for (int cc = 1; c + cc <= str.Length; cc++)
            {
                yield return str.Substring(c, cc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's easy and readable with this LINQ query:

```
string longestIntersection = "E15QD(A)".GetSubstrings()
    .Intersect("NQE18H".GetSubstrings())
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();  // E1
```

[`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is also quite efficient since it's using a set. One note: if one both strings is larger than the other then it's more efficient(in terms of memory) to use it first:

```
longString.GetSubstrings().Intersect(shortString.GetSubstrings())
```

Comment: While the details provided by OP may specifically refer to strings, the actual titled question, which is how anyone is going to find this, lacks any such specificity. So I don't feel this (or any answer provided thus far) is an appropriate answer to the question asked.

Comment: @arkon: in general on stackoverflow people try to answer the question that is asked in the question body. We cannot give a solution for all problems that match to a given title(which often is not very meaningful or too general). Feel free to ask a question so we can help.

Comment: @arkon: changed the question title to the same that OP used in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
string similar = null;

for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
{
    string s = s1.Substring(0, i + 1);

     if (s2.Contains(s))
     {
         similar = s;
     }
}

char[] result = similar.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: In my initial test this works! Thanks man. @TimSchmelter in the comment of the original post also provided a link for solution of LongestSubstring. I will upload that answer aswell.

Answer (score -1):

@TimSchmelter provided the link to this answer in the comments of the original post.

```
public int LongestCommonSubstring(string str1, string str2, out string sequence)
    {
        sequence = string.Empty;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
            return 0;

        int[,] num = new int[str1.Length, str2.Length];
        int maxlen = 0;
        int lastSubsBegin = 0;
        StringBuilder sequenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str1[i] != str2[j])
                    num[i, j] = 0;
                else
                {
                    if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
                        num[i, j] = 1;
                    else
                        num[i, j] = 1 + num[i - 1, j - 1];

                    if (num[i, j] > maxlen)
                    {
                        maxlen = num[i, j];
                        int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i, j] + 1;
                        if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin)
                        {//if the current LCS is the same as the last time this block ran
                            sequenceBuilder.Append(str1[i]);
                        }
                        else //this block resets the string builder if a different LCS is found
                        {
                            lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
                            sequenceBuilder.Length = 0; //clear it
                            sequenceBuilder.Append(str1.Substring(lastSubsBegin, (i + 1) - lastSubsBegin));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sequence = sequenceBuilder.ToString();
        return maxlen;
    }
```