# Find the longest common substring of an array of strings

Tags: c#, string

For example,

```
var input = new[] {"dog", "doge", "suchverydoge", "suchverywowdoge"};
var result = GetCommonSubstring(input);
```

the `result` should be "dog".

Comment: what have you tried? have you seen this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem ?

Comment: Look at Tim's Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953208/find-longest-substring-in-an-array-of-strings-and-remove-it-from-all-the-element

Comment: Here is another one with C# code: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_Common_Substring#C.23

Comment: I had searched Google for it, and the top result was this [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953208/find-longest-substring-in-an-array-of-strings-and-remove-it-from-all-the-element), but it was about finding the common substring of two strings, one from input and another in the given array.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: no, that question is a duplicate. A `string[]` is a `IList<string>` so you could use the accepted answer. Look at the last example. `string result = input.GetLongestCommonSubstring(); // dog`

Comment: You can use Dynamic Programming to find Longest Common Subsequence (LCS) of 2 strings. However, to find LCS of multiple strings is NP-hard problem. I don't see any constraints that make it solvable otherwise

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. I only skimmed the selected answer's code and thought it was getting the common strings of each two strings, since the method's return type is not just a string, but basically strings. I looked at it again, and I found I needed to call `FirstOrDefault()` to get the result.